# How to use external sd card as internal memory

Tags: external-sd, motorola

I have a 16 GB class 10 SD card and want to swap it with my 2gb internal memory.

MOTO E 1st edition
rooted

Answer (score 0):

That's not how internal storage works. Other than the `/sdcard` partition you see using your stock file manager, there are a lot of other partitions such as `/system` `/data` `/recovery` etc.

All those partitions are also stored on your phone's internal storage. When you start your phone `/boot` loads your `/system` and makes Android run. Then it mounts `/data` which includes all your user data. Even if you can manage to install this entire `/` partition on an sdcard, a Stock Android ROM will not recognize an external sdcard as its main storage. Maybe there can be custom ROMs that support such option but I have never heard of such a case. That, of course, doesn't mean it doesn't exist.